# Awk multiple transformation / separators in once

Tags: csv, awk

I have to transform (preprocess) a CSV file, by generating / inserting a new column, being the result of the concat of existing columns.

For example, transform:

```
A|B|C|D|E
```

into:

```
A|B|C|D|C > D|E
```

In this example, I do it with:

```
cat myfile.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$4 = $4 OFS $3" > "$4} 1'
```

But now I have something more complex to do, and dont find how to do this.

I have to transform:

```
A|B|C|x,y,z|E
```

into

```
A|B|C|x,y,z|C > x,C > y,C > z|E
```

How can it be done in awk (or other command) efficiently (my csv file can contains thousands of lines)?

Thanks.

Comment: If C, x, y, or z can be/contain any regexp metachar or `&` or `\\1` then make sure to test those with any solution that uses a *sub() function.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` (for `gensub` which is a GNU extension):

```
awk -F'|' '{$6=$5; $5=gensub(/(^|,)/,"\\1" $3 " > ","g",$4); print}' OFS='|'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split the 4th field into an array:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {split($4,a,",");$4="";for(i=1;i in a;i++)$4=($4? $4 "," : "") $3 " > " a[i]} 1' myfile.csv
A|B|C|C > x,C > y,C > z|E
```

Comment: This is the only solution so far that'll work for any characters/strings in $3 or $4 as it's just using literal string operations.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest is the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{t=$4;gsub(/[^,]+/,$3" > &",t);$4 = $4 OFS t}1'
```

we make a copy of the fourth field in variable `t`. In there, we replace every string which does not contain the new separator (`,`) by the content of the third field followed by `>` and the original matched string (`&`).